# wordpress network plugins page prompts login

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

I am experiencing very weird behavior from my wordpress website.

My network section of the website keeps redirecting me to a login page that i cannot login with my administrator user of the website. 
However when i use the url of the network pages like dashboard or plugins i see the same login page which this time i can actually login with my administrator user.

to clarify this: 
lets say i have example.com/wp-admin/network/plugins.php

if i manually type this in the url section i get a login page which my admin user logs in no problem

if i use the link in the wordpress dashboard to access the same plugins page of my network drop down i get a login page that doesn't accept my admin user.

now in this situation my question is 
1- Should the wordpress prompt login each time i want to access my network section. How can i cancel this?
2- Why are the links for the network section not working.

My guess is that the www.example.com and example.com for the network and one of the websites are not redirecting right.

Please Guide Me.

UPDATE: 
I'm afraid that I was unable to find the origin of the issue.

I have performed various tests that you can double-check below.
* I have deactivated all plugins for the entire Multisite network.
* Deactivated the SSL Force feature of Let's Encrypt tool.
* Tested by opening the website directly from the server in order to bypass CloudFlare servers.
* Restored the theme from a backup and reverted that modification after the test.
* Tested with different browsers(Chrome, Mozilla, Safari)
* Configured the correct Rewrite directives for the Multisite application defined in the .htaccess file as the old ones were for a regular single-site application. 
* Tested different PHP versions.
* Confirmed that all WordPress core files are not modified or customized.
* Activated a default WordPress theme for the tests, and reverted to the default one after that.

After the mentioned tests, I would suppose that the issue is caused by a conflict in the database records.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if I understand the issue, but I would recommend to turn off all plugins and switch to the default theme. If the problem still exists, I would think about reinstalling WordPress

Comment: This sounds like HTTP and HTTPS modes are getting cross wired, Check the address bar before and after the login prompt and you'll know for sure

Comment: @Jamie_D both addresses are https, but the difference between clicking the network link and manually entering the wp-admin/network/plugins.php is that when i click the link i see a redirect link which gives a login prompt that doesnt accept my admin user, but when i manually enter the url i also get a login page which this time my admin user does function!

Comment: Are you using a custom login form?

Comment: its on the theme yes, but when i login from that or any other way (/wp-admin) i still have the same problem. When i click the network link on my dashboard, the problem appears and it redirects me to the link below: 
wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fwp-admin%2Fnetwork%2F&reauth=1

Comment: @meck373 how would i reinstall wordpress and keep my posts and theme customization that i have done? and also my plugin data that i have collected and setup?